# Android, how to set alarm service to the predefined date time and run notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, statusbar

I would like to add into my application background service which takes given datetime and ID pointing to the table row with additional informations and in given time displays status Bar notification.

Could somebody give me a simple example how can I do it?

Many Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using AlarmManager to schedule whatever process you wanted to do? (https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

UPDATE: pass parameter to the intent

For example (copied):

```
// create Intent 
PendingIntent alarmIntent;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", "ABX1000"); // your ID
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

 // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
 // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
 alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

And in your receiver, get the intent....

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // Implement code here to be performed when 
        // broadcast is detected
     String myID= intent.getStringExtra("ID"); 
 }
```

Comment: Hello, yes i looked on this article, but i would like to store with alarm also some addition informations, for example ID.

Comment: You mean passing the ID to the receiver? You can set it (ID for example) when you create the intent, then retrieve it when the receiver gets fired up.. See updated code example

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a notification or intent using pending intent.
example is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)